# How do I use the TOR Network with Microsoft Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, socks, tor, anonymity

I have a VBA script that I use in Internet Explorer. I want to use TOR to surf privately and I have installed the Tor Vidalia package. When searching for a solution on how to use IE with TOR I find Privoxy solutions, however I dont have a ready set up package for that and I did not suceed in installing it.

How do I set up IE to use the socks proxy that TOR/Vidalia provides?

Answer (score 0):

Tor uses socks proxy. Internet explorer needs http-proxy. Privoxy has http-proxy. Install both privoxy and tor. Change privoxy settings yo point to tor address and port. Change IE proxy settings to use privoxy port and address.